# Conflict in executing Python script in terminal and Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

Created and develop a project in Pycharm , now i have many package and `.py` files.

in Pycharm, imported modules (from same project)  to another `.py` file , handled as well but if run any `.py` file from terminal with command `python xxx.py`  occur error :

```
ImportError: No module named 'modulenamed'
```

use exactly the same command that the Pycharm generates during the execution of the script, but there is still a problem.( in venvs )

```
/directory/project/venvs/bin/python /directory/project/package1/script1.py
```

figure

```
├── package1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script1.py    => from package2 import script1
├── package2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script1.py
└── something.py
```

What is the solution to running scripts without Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

give relative path :

```
from directory.project.package2 import script1
```

Comment: must change all script files from pycharm syntax to python pure ?

Comment: @alisarkhosh what do you mean by 'pycharm syntax'?

Comment: @mx0 pycharm automatically handle import file and modules but with pure python must be handle import modules with os or sys libs